# BeautifulSoup locating iframe and its attribute

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I have to get iframe src with beautiful soup

```
<div class="divclass">
 <div id="simpleid">
  <iframe width="300" height="300" src="http://google.com>
```

I could use selenium with code:

```
iframe1 = driver.find_element_by_class_name("divclass")
iframe = iframe1.find_element_by_tag_name("iframe").get_attribute("src")
```

but selenium is too slow for this task.

I've been looking for solution here on stackoverflow and tried several codes but always get error 403 while using urllib (changing browser agent is not working, still 403 error) or I get "None"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very good question.
Looking at the site you're trying to get that iframe from using that lib, you have to get the contents of  tag in that div, and then base64 decode it and you should be done.
Seeing how you do things, don't stop! You're going to be a great programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Use soup.find_all('tag you want to search')

```
>>> from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
>>> html = '''
... <div class="divclass">
...  <div id="simpleid">
...   <iframe width="300" height="300" src="http://google.com">
... '''
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
>>> soup.find_all('iframe')
[<iframe height="300" src="http://google.com" width="300">
</iframe>]
>>> soup.find_all('iframe')[0]['src']
u'http://google.com'
>>>
```

Comment: Tried it before, and it only find smaller iframe with advertisement, the one I want prints empty [ ]

Comment: It would be great if you can provide the link, or may be a piece of code. I am not sure what is wrong with your code but I guess this is the best way to approach it.

Comment: First the site is blocked, so I guess I am helpless here (as per my ISP). You can try to check if you can modify anything or not, else you can go for regex approach which is kind of little hard. Still the find_all() function should have worked.

Comment: What is the purpose of the '[0] in the soup.find_all('iframe')[0]['src']?

Comment: find_all returns list of values, so you need to access the first occurrence by [0], best thing you can do is that if you want first occurrence then simply type soup.find('iframe')
for this you don't have to specify [0]